# can anyone explain where the constants or const variables stored?

Tags: c++, memory, constants

As we all know, C++'s memory model can be divided to five blocks: stack, heap, free blocks, global/static blocks, const blocks. I can understand the first three blocks and I also know variables like `static int xx` are stored in the 4th blocks, and also the "hello world"-string constant, but what is stored in the 5th blocks-const blocks? and , like `int a = 10`, where does the "10" stored? Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: C++ imposes no specific memory model. For all the language cares, everything could be stored on the heap.

Comment: if you explain the differences between them - i'll be able to explain the 5th..

Comment: The `10` itself isn't stored anywhere, it is a value that is used to initialize the variable. What memory is used by the variable itself depends on how the variable was defined.

Comment: what the use of the 5th blocks are?

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and [value categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

Comment: @Xeo: It does now (although it still doesn't specify this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between string literals and primitive constants. String literals are usually stored with the code in a separate area (for historical reasons this block is often called the "text block"). Primitive constants, on the other hand, are somewhat special: they can be stored in the "text" block as well, but their values can also be "baked" into the code itself. For example, when you write

```
// Global integer constant
const int a = 10;

int add(int b) {
    return b + a;
}
```

the return expression could be translated into a piece of code that does not reference `a` at all. Instead of producing binary code that looks like this

```
LOAD R0, <stack>+offset(b)
LOAD R1, <address-of-a>
ADD R0, R1
RET
```

the compiler may produce something like this:

```
LOAD R0, <stack>+offset(b)
ADD R0, #10 ; <<== Here #10 means "integer number 10"
RET
```

Essentially, despite being stored with the rest of the constants, `a` is cut out of the compiled code.

As far as integer literals constants go, they have no address at all: they are always "baked" into the code: when you reference them, instructions that load explicit values are generated, in the same way as shown above.

Comment: ok , now i understand it , i have a different problem.In which situation can complier allocates memory for varibles just when the code be complied ?

Comment: @XiaosongHe When the variable is constant, and you do not request its address or produce a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

> and , like int a = 10, where does the "10" stored?

It's an implementation detail. Will likely be a part of generated code and be turned into something like

```
mov eax, 10
```

in assembly.

The same will happen to definitions like

```
const int myConst = 10;
```

unless you try to get address of myConst like that:

```
const int *ptr = &myConst;
```

in which case the compiler will have to put the value of 10 into the dedicated block of memory (presumably 5th in your numeration).