# Inline functions instead of simple macros with constant

Tags: c++, performance, macros, inline

In general in C++, you want to use constant instead of defining constants with `#define` as there is type checking and this is a good thing.

```
    #define   MYCONST 10;   // NO
    const int MYCONST = 10; // OK.
```

This is fine, but suppose I want to improve the performance of my app; if I have to read that constant still I might read it (I hope to be correct) from any cache level from L1 to L3 and this would introduce slowness.

Would it be better to define that constant as simple inline function like below?

```
    inline int MYCONST()
    {
       return 10;
    }
```

Am I correct when I should expect some improvement?

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983642/can-anyone-explain-where-the-constants-or-const-variables-stored) for integer it seems that it depends on the compiler and the type I am using.

Comment: Why don't you just implement and measure? You probably won't notice a difference at all, because the compiler is too smart. By the way, reserve ALL_UPPERCASE for macros.

Comment: With all of those, the compiler is likely to make the correct decision about how to obtain maximum performance from whatever calculations use the constant.

Comment: "read it  [...] from any cache level from L1 to L3" - when the compiler optimizes, those constants are put in the code segment (the linked answer explains this as "baking"). there's no additional read.

Comment: OK, I get it No cache involved..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and no: when you define something like

```
const int MYCONST = 10;
```

The value will *not* be read from "any cache level" but the compiler (at least any compiler build in the last 20 years) will issue exactly the same code as if you had used macros (or literals, which is equivalent), i.e. it will be placed directly inside the machine code.

Therefore your second suggestion (using an inline function) will not only have no performance benefit at all but prevent many uses of constants (like `char my_array[MYCONST]`), not to mention the lack of readability, wasted space etc. of your code.

Just follow the main C++ credo and use constants, there's nothing wrong with that :) ...

Comment: Thanks Martin,I get it..Just I never wnet so low level before regarding constant.. I wanted some expert opinion.

Comment: One more detail,  is it something that applies to all datatypes? double, char, string??

Comment: It applies to all *basic* datatypes (int,byte,double,float etc). For char pointers (i.e. C strings) the content (the characters) will be placed in the data segment and the pointer will be treated as constant (again this is the same or even better as with macros). For Objects, (like `std::string("Hello World")`), the `const` approach will be even much better: in this case, a macro would result in calling the constructor for every *use* of the macro whereas the constructor for the const object will only be called once. There really is no drawback of using `const` for constants ...

Answer (score 1):

I think that defining a `const` is better practice anyway, but I also suspect that many compilers would not be able correctly to process a construct such as

```
char myBuffer[MYCONST()];
```

without issuing an error message.